# Opening the camera in a different process

Tags: android, memory, process, camera, android-lifecycle

One of my apps has a serious activity recreation issue in some `Kitkat Samsung` devices. The problem appears more frequently when taking pictures, and it isn't observed in crappy `Jellybean Samsung`s with half the RAM. Logs show a low memory condition, although no `OutOfMemoryException`s are being thrown. I think there's a more aggressive activity closing policy in `Kitkat` (or else the default camera app is leaky).

I was wondering whether the OS closes my activities when my app's memory is high, or  instead it closes them when the total memory used by all apps is high. If the OS had a per-process threshold, then maybe opening the camera in a different process might help.

I know it is possible to start a service in its own process using the `process` attribute in the manifest. Assuming no equivalent attribute exists for `Activities`, if I started a proxy service in its own process and then started an activity from this service, would the activity run in this process as well?

Comment: @Onik Well, those paragraphs are the background. Maybe there's somebody out there that knows the OS memory management in deep and could help me understand what is going on. I've known about the Lollipop memory leak problem, and also the webview leak, but AFAIK these do not apply in Kitkats with updated webviews.

Comment: Activities also can be launched in their own processes http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc

Comment: If you use camera via Intent, you already use camera in a separate process. The camera app that is launched may be chosen by the user, and it may be huge, pushing your process out of memory. Your app should be prepared to be a good citizen in the Android system, keeping the state on exit, and restoring it when the Intent result is returned. But  if this destruction is not acceptable for your use case, you must implement a "custom camera" inside your app. Operating such camera is not an inherently memory-intensive task.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour described is totally agreed with the [Application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) documentation from which it is clear that *"opening the camera in a different process"* won't help you, just because this is what already happens by default:

> When the system starts a component, it starts the process for that app (if it's not already running) and instantiates the classes needed for the component. For example, if your app starts the activity in the camera app that captures a photo, that activity runs in the process that belongs to the camera app, not in your app's process.

So when the camera app is brought to foreground, your app goes to background, which makes it be one of the candidates to be killed by the system when it is low on memory as per [Processes and Application Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html). You're witnessing a normal OS's behaviour. Total amount of RAM isn't a key point. Free memory of the amount available for the process in foreground matters.

With that said, the answer to your question is **No**. Any `Activity` starts and runs within the application (process) it was originally declared in through the manifest file, no matter which process the start request comes from.

The command

```
adb shell ps | grep 'app_name'
```

will tell you which processes your and camera app are running on.

Two apps can run in the same process though, but the necessary prerequisite for this is the same signature of the apps... From [Application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html):

> It's possible to arrange for two apps to share the same Linux user ID... Apps with the same user ID can also arrange to run in the same Linux process and share the same VM (the apps must also be signed with the same certificate).

Comment: According to [this developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes) it is possible to use the `android:process` for activities as well.

Comment: Correct. While you can use the attribute within your app(s), you cannot change it for a camera app, so no matter what value of `process` you set, the camera app `Activity` will be running in a different process (with the default name if the attribute wasn't set in the manifest).

Comment: I see. It maybe useful for internal camera activities based in SurfaceHolder though.

Comment: There is nothing "bad" in an `Activity` recreation. This is the way OS behave. If it kills the process that's in background, it'll take care of recovering it when the process is about to be brought to foreground again. A developer's purpose is to handle a proper `Activity`/`Service` state saving/restoring in order for a user it looked like the app had never been killed.