# Activity being destroyed when taking photo

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When I do startActivityForResult to take a photo, the underlying Activity is destroyed. Even when I put

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

in the manifest, any ideas would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: You might find some clarification in [Opening the camera in a different process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343779/opening-the-camera-in-a-different-process/35537588#35537588).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your process is being terminated while your app is in the background. This is perfectly normal and will happen in many other cases, not just this one. You will need to adjust your application to deal with this situation (e.g., use the saved instance state `Bundle`).

Comment: Surely this would not happen when only one app is open?

Comment: @bdavies6086: Sure it will. First, there are many other processes running and needing to run, for background work, even if you think "only one app is open". Second, the camera app may be requesting a large heap, which puts increased memory pressure on the system and will cause it to eject other apps more aggressively. More importantly, *users* will not often be in a situation "when only one app is open". So, you need to handle the case where your process is terminated.

Comment: Good point! Fair enough, began to implement the changes! Cheers for the advice :)